# Replace numbers on continuous legend in ggplot with arbitrary text

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a plot made with ggplot with a continuous colour scale. Is it possible to replace the numbers on the scale legend with text?

[image]

For example, instead of having 5, 10, 15, 20 here, I'd like to just have "High" where 20 is and "Low" where 5 is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using mtcars as example data. Simply set the breaks and/or the labels, like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg, color = hp)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_continuous(breaks = c(100, 200, 300), labels = c("low", "med", "high"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

```
library(ggplot2) 
ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg, color = hp)) + 
geom_point() + 
scale_color_continuous(type = "viridis", 
breaks = c(100, 200, 300), labels = c("low", "med", "high"))
```

This builds off of Stefan's answer using mtcars but adds the viridis scale that op uses.